# Where to store password - 3rd party API

Tags: password-protection

I am working on an application where i have to call a API from my java backend code which requires me to pass user id and password in the request. This password is to be rotated every 30 days. Question:

1. Where should the password be saved so that it is available on run time, don't want to store it in DB as it will not perform efficiently.
2. The updated password should be available to the service calling the third party so that there is no restart required for the server

Database doesn't seems like a good option as can't save the password in clear text there and fetching from DB before each API call doesn't seems like a good idea.

There will be multiple instance of service running on production hence storing in a text file doesn't seems a good option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could set them as "environment option" and pass them to the application start as input argument.

One option could be also to set it as "environment variable" and then get it as system property.

Comment: That means on rotation of password, i will have to restart my application which is not appropriate.